# mysql: finding groups of records within a specified time period

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have the following transactional data:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| CustomerID | TransactionID |     TransactionDate |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|          1 |             1 | 2015-01-22 15:09:43 |
|          1 |             2 | 2015-01-22 16:58:13 |
|          1 |             3 | 2015-01-23 07:05:53 |
|          2 |             4 | 2015-02-02 21:12:28 |
|          2 |             5 | 2015-02-02 22:01:59 |
|          3 |             6 | 2015-02-03 19:50:47 |
|          2 |             7 | 2015-02-04 16:12:08 |
|          4 |             8 | 2015-02-05 17:13:29 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

*TransactionDate, BTW, is stored as a unix timestamp, not a string representation of a date. I just converted it to make it easier to read here.*

I'm trying to craft a query that will tell me which customers (by ID) purchased 3 or more times within a 24-hour window. In this (admittedly basic) example, the only customer to fit that criteria is #1, because those three transactions all happened within a 24-hour period. Customer #2 wouldn't because only two transactions happened within 24 hours; the third was outside the 24-hour window from the first. All I care about is the customer ID; I don't need to know which transactions were involved or the actual transaction date. Currently I'm doing this via code - run the query which returns the table above into a PHP array, transform the results using code like this:

```
foreach ($results as $result)
    $data[$result['CustomerID']][] = array(
        'TransactionID' => $result['TransactionID'],
        'TransactionDate' => $result['TransactionDate']
    );
```

...which gives me an array like this...

```
$data = array(
    '1' => array(
        array(
            'TransactionID' => '1',
            'TransactionDate' => '2015-01-22 15:09:43'
        ),
        array(
            'TransactionID' => '2',
            'TransactionDate' => '2015-01-22 16:58:13'
        ),
        array(
            'TransactionID' => '3',
            'TransactionDate' => '2015-01-23 07:05:53'
        ),
    ),
    '2' => array(
        array(
            'TransactionID' => '4',
            'TransactionDate' => '2015-02-02 21:12:28'
        ),
        array(
            'TransactionID' => '5',
            'TransactionDate' => '2015-02-02 22:01:59'
        ),
        array(
            'TransactionID' => '7',
            'TransactionDate' => '2015-02-04 16:12:08'
        ),
    ),
    // etc.
)
```

...and then go through each customer and see if the third record is within 24 hours of the first record, if the fourth record is within 24 hours of the second record, etc., depending on how many purchase records there are for that customer in that time period. If at any point I find three records within a 24-hour window, I flag that customer ID and move on to the next (I don't really care how many 24-hour blocks of 3+ transactions I find, just that I found at least one).

If it were as simple as 8 transaction records, I would be happy leaving this as a bit of procedural code like I've outlined here; but when I'm hauling 92,000 records from the database into PHP for processing (and each record is more like 70 fields, not 3), I start to hit serious memory and timeout problems. I know, because I've worked with large datasets before (in the millions of rows), that any database server worth its salt can crunch through these kinds of calculations a lot faster than PHP running as a module under Apache. What I don't know is how I can calculate time between records directly in the query environment. Is this kind of processing even possible within MySQL?

Comment: You could use [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php) in mysql.

Comment: I'm trying not to procedurally loop through 90,000 records in my stored procedure. Ideally I would like that `timediff()` result to be a calculated column in the query, which I can then pick out using a `HAVING` clause. It's more a matter of being able to craft a query where row n is calculated based on the contents of row n-1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    SELECT frst.CustomerID, frst.TransactionDate as firstdate,
    min(scnd.TransactionDate) as secdate, 
    min(third.TransactionDate) as thirddate FROM so29518803 frst
    inner join so29518803 scnd on scnd.CustomerID = frst.CustomerID and
    scnd.TransactionDate > frst.TransactionDate inner join so29518803 third on
    scnd.CustomerID = third.CustomerID and
    third.TransactionDate>scnd.TransactionDate group by frst.CustomerID,
    frst.TransactionDate 
having timestampdiff(second,firstdate, thirddate) < 86400
```

With an index on CustomerID and TransactionDate that query runs quite fast.
However, if you would ever need to check for larger number of transactions within time period, this approach will not work.